# Django update or create where field like/beings with

Tags: django, django-queryset

Is it possible to do an update or create where a field beginswith? or like?
I want to update or create a record that begins with a certain string, but everything after the string could be different

For example:

```
notes_data = 'DB1223 - blah blah, stats : 342, bad : 311'

notes_obj, record = Notes.objects.update_or_create(
    defaults={
        'notes'  : notes_data,
        },
    'notes'  : notes_data.beginswith('DB1223'),
)
```

Comment: What do you want to set the value to when the record doesn't exist?

Comment: if the string does not begin with DB1223 then create a record, if an existing record begins with DB1223 then update that one instead or creating one

Comment: Create the record with what value? Update the record with what value?

Comment: ive updated the question with a bit more info, hopefully this helps?

Comment: the notes_data is scraped from an external site and put in a string. but it can be coverted if it will help make the query work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`__startswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#startswith) with `update_or_create`:

```
notes_obj, created = Notes.objects.update_or_create(
    defaults={
        'notes': notes_data,
        },
    notes__startwith='DB1223',
)
```